# Saving video with title or file name

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation, photosframework

I am working on an app that saves video to the user's library. I would like to display the videos with a user inputed title on a table view controller, like "Amy's 1st Birthday." This is my first time working with the Photos Framework and `AVFoundation`, and I'm not sure how to begin.

My guess to build a object model to save a title string with the saved video, but I'm not sure how to associate it with the video being saved. Is there a property of `PHAsset` that will let me do something similar?

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You may associate the title with the PHObject's localIdentifier property which is unique for every asset.

Comment: can i later on get on chronological order?

Comment: You can set a predicate on fetchAssetsInAssetCollection's options parameter. And like any other NSPredicate you set the predicate sort descriptors and predicate condition (for localIdentifier comparison & sorting via creationDate property).

Comment: i just used a timestamp and and identifier in last...and that worked as